# Error al introducir un contacto -- Entered a contact name incorrectly

Tags: contacts

He introducido como segundo nombre el primer apellido de un contacto:
Irene Martínez Mas. Cómo puedo corregirlo? La aplicación me dice que no tengo permiso para hacerlo.

I have entered as the second name as the first name of a contact: How can I correct it? The message tells me that I do not have permission to do it.

Comment: Based on the information at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange where it says "What should I do if someone else makes a post that is not in English?", I'm following those instructions and voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Puede ser que tu registro de usuario no incluye el permiso "CiviCRM: editar todos los contactos" - tendrias que pedir al administrador del sistema que añade este permiso a un perfil que está asociado tu registro de usuario (e.g. personal, editor, etc.).

Espero que esto ayude!

Tamar

Comment: Oops I didn't see you had answered before I voted to close - the review queue doesn't show the complete question. Sorry!

Comment: Translation-"It may be that your user registration does not include the "CiviCRM: edit all contacts" permission - you need to ask the system administrator to add this permission to a profile that is associated with your user record (eg staff, editor, etc.) ."